# Iterating over a NSDictionary to add values to an object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am trying to iterate through a NSDictionary and add all the values in that dictionary to an object. So i added new cocoa class file to my project and subclassed it with NSObject. (named it customClass)
In my custom class.h:

```
- (void)printDir;     // iterate through the direcory and print it.

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *objDictionary;
```

In customClass.m the defination of printDir method is as:

```
- (void)printDir {
    _objDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc ]init];
    for(id key in _objDictionary) {
    id value = [_objDictionary objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"Values in Objects Dictionary");
    NSLog(@"%@",value);
    }
}
```

In my ViewController.m i am trying to iterate through a NSDirectory and add all the values of that directory to the NSMutableDictionary of the object. For which,

```
for(id key in jsonDictionary.allKeys) {
    id value = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:key];
    [obj.objDictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
}
```

When i run the project the printDir method of the object get called, however the for loop does not execute. Can someone point out where i am going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: check the dictionary is empty or contains values?

Comment: jsonDictionary contains lots of key-values, so that ain't an issue.

Comment: Did you actually `[[alloc]init]` a new `NSMutableDictionary` and assign it to `objDictionary` at any point?  If not it will be nil and therefor `setObject:` won't do anything.  You could also just say `obj.objDictionary=[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:jsonDictionary] mutableCopy]`

Comment: @Paulw11 - thanks for pointing that out, but now when i add a breakpoint to printDir method and step over a couple of times, it shows that _objDictionary has 0 key/values, and hence the for loop does not run.

Comment: I think you should first get all keys. Like NSArray * allKeys = _objDictionary.allKeys;

Comment: _objDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc ]init]; do this in init method of your customClass not in printDir.

Comment: You are now setting `objDictionary` to an empty dictionary before you try to print it.  You need to alloc/init before you try and add the objects from the JSON dictionary in *the second for loop* you have shown

Comment: great help @Paulw11 and everyone else, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
_objDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc ]init];
```

Change this line in your `printDir` method to init method of your custom class. The problem now is each time when you reach your `printDir` method, it is re-assigning the `_objDictionary` to nil. So the loop will not execute

Answer (score 0):

In printDir Function you are allocating a dictionary **objDictionary** again.... so it over right your actual value supplies by your view controller .... You just change your function to this 
In .h file

```
- (void)printDirwithDictionary :(NSMutableDictionary *)dict;
```

And in .m file

```
- (void)printDirwithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict {
    _objDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dict]
    for(id key in _objDictionary) {
    id value = [_objDictionary objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"Values in Objects Dictionary");
    NSLog(@"%@",value);
    }
}
```

In ViewController.m Follow This code

```
  NSMutableDictionary *dictToPass = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
     for(id key in jsonDictionary.allKeys) {
        id value = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:key];
         [dictToPass setObject:value forKey:key];
    }
    [obj printDirWithDictionary:dictToPass];
```

And Call from View Controller will be like this
And Then Follow the sameprocedure . Hope This will Work Properly .